PostgreSQL server using SSL via Python - Unable to Execute DML comands
I can do SELECT on a table in a PostgreSQL database (hosted on a secure server) via Python using a SSH connection. But when I try to do INSERT or CREATE on the database, I get the following error:

could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)
SSL SYSCALL error: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)

I can perform DDL and DML commands using DBeaver while connecting with same DB instance from my PC.
Could you help me with what I am missing?Code Snippet Select Working and Insert/Create Failing
I have consulted multiple blogs/documentations but I'm unable to do an insert.

Have you tried to handle exceptions?  The error you're getting is not the ultimate cause of the problem.  It may be permissions or something else but you're letting exceptions fall through so it's a bit hard to tell.

i handled the exception it prints only.   could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)
SSL SYSCALL error: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)

When I executed the same sql command on dbeaver it ran fine.  In Python SELECT is done fine as well. COnfused.

Perhaps then it's related to the SSH tunnel?  Is there any way to run without that?

Not in this case.  Why am I able to Read data from Tables from the same SSH tunnel?

@RobertR maybe this task can help you
